# SSIS Bulk Insert Task- Unable to enter destination table manually

Tags: sql, ssis

I am Editing the SSIS package in Dev environment and I want to configure the package so that it can be deployed in another environment/Server, as I cannot the access the target server in current environment, am unable to select the destination table, can't manually type either.

[image]

Comment: You have to set up a dev environment and restore a backup production database or run the database scripts then do some change on the ssis package.